# HttpGet.abort() / HttpPost.abort() doesn't always abort immediately

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I'm using Apache HttpComponents 4.2.1 and I'm having trouble getting HttpGet.abort() and HttpPost.abort() to always abort immediately. It works most of the time, but occasionally the connection will block until it times out. I noticed this only happens when I explicitly set a timeout value.

Here's my test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        testAbort();
    }
}

public static void testAbort() throws Exception {
    String urlString = "http://slow.website.com";

    final HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urlString);

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpParams httpParams = httpClient.getParams();

                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10000); // issue doesn't occur if I comment this line

                httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    Thread t = new Thread(runnable);

    t.start();

    Thread.sleep(100);

    httpGet.abort();
}
```

Here's a sample of the output I get:

```
Request already aborted
Request already aborted
Request already aborted
Socket closed
Request already aborted
Connection has been shut down
Socket closed
Socket closed
Connect to slow.website.com:80 timed out
Connect to www.website.com:80 timed out
```

You may need to increase the number of iterations or fiddle with the Thread.sleep() value to see the issue occur.

According to HttpComponent docs, "When an HTTP request is aborted its execution thread blocked in an I/O operation is guaranteed to unblock by throwing a InterruptedIOException" ([link](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d4e285))

I'm running Mac OS X 10.8 (Java version 1.6.0_29).

Any ideas what might be the issue?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer to your issue here? I am in a similar predicament (I need to be able to abort a transaction.

Comment: I created a bug [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1228). The issue seems isolated to OS X, so the devs closed the ticket with the comment "I can only attribute this issue to 'peculiarities' of Mac OS / Apple JVM. I can't really do much about it." :(

Comment: can anyone answer this question? I have the same problem. i don't know what must I do.